# How come some shell commands in Jupyter don't require exclamation points?

Tags: python, jupyter

`ls` and `pwd` are a few examples that can be run without the bang beforehand. But other shell commands require a `!` before. I'm curious as to what these are called. They're not built-in magic commands, are they?

Comment: Does `%ls` or `%pwd` work?

Comment: `%ls`, `!ls`, and `ls` work. The first is a magic command, the second is a shell command, but the third is a ...?

Comment: Depending on settings, the `%` can be omitted from magics.  This is called `automagic`.